# create() got multiple values for keyword argument 'date_to_reserved'

Tags: django-rest-framework

```
class DateToReserveSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    date = serializers.CharField()
    day = serializers.CharField()
    time = serializers.CharField()
    def __init__(self,date,time,day):
        self.date = date
        self.day= day
        self.time = time

    def getter(self):
        return f'{self.date}/{self.day} in {self.time}'
```

```
class ReservingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    code_token = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    date_to_reserved =  serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
  
    class Meta:
        model = Reserve
        fields = '__all__'
    def create(self,validated_data):
        request = self.context.get("request")
        self.date_to_reserved = request.data['date_to_reserved']
        DateToReserveSerializer.__init__(self,self.date_to_reserved[0],self.date_to_reserved[1],self.date_to_reserved[2])
        try:
            code = code_generator.random_code_generator()
            return Reserve.objects.create(**validated_data,code_token=code,date_to_reserved=str(DateToReserveSerializer.getter(self)))
            
        except IntegrityError:
            if 'unique constraint':
                return self.create(validated_data)
```

I tried to save some data into my database in **DRF**. I got an error! the **date_to_reserved** in my model is CharField....

Comment: This is the definition of the serializer. can you also include the usage of this serializer which resulted into error?

Comment: now i try to fix it..... let me if i couldnt fix it i will tell you everything

Comment: i used split method for splitting input data and save it into my database... and i still get an error! it says "key word argument `date_to_reserved` has got multiple values". and i dont know why?